# Different behavior in javascripts code

Tags: javascript, function

Different behavior in javascripts code

***First :***

```
(function(){
   c();
   var c=function (){
      console.log("C");
   }
})();

Error : Uncaught TypeError: c is not a function
```

vs

```
(function(){
   c();
   function c(){
      console.log("C");
   }
})();

C
```

***Second :***

```
var a;
console.log(a);
a=10;

10
```

vs

```
(function(){
   var a; 
   console.log(a);
   a=10;
})()

undefined
```

Please help me to understand this behaviors.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### First

```
(function(){c();var c=function (){console.log("C");}})()
```

`c` is not yet defined, so it's an error.

```
(function(){c();function c(){console.log("C");}})()
```

`function something() {}` is always [called at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname), so `c` is defined here.

### Second

```
var a;console.log(a);a=10;
```

The assignment returns the value of the assignment, so it's `10`. It's also the reason why you can write `a = b = 4`.

```
(function(){var a; console.log(a);a=10;})()
```

The function doesn't return (there is not `return`) anything, so it's `undefined`.

If we are talking about about the `console.log` result here, they are both `undefined` since `a` is not yet defined.